# tester 1 is able to get his facebook albums but tester 2 is not able to get his facebook albums using facebook javascript Api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Tester 1 is able to get his facebook albums but tester 2 is not able to get his facebook albums using facebook javascript Api ??

I have created facebook web-app using javascript API.
My App is in Development Mode I have included 3 tester in it.

I am Able to get tester one facebook albums using following code.

```
FB.api(
 "/me/albums",
  function (response) {
   if (response && !response.error) {
     /* handle the result */

     console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
     console.log(response)
     console.log("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
   }
 }
);
```

but same thing i am not able to do with second tester.

I have added tester one before 15 days back & tester two yesterday.
i have also mentioned permissions also.

this seems quite strange..  please help me out.
Thank You In advance.

Comment: Call `/me/permissions` to verify that the access token actually includes the permission.

Comment: thank you  @CBroe ...yes both testers permissions are different !!  one tester don't have all permissions. can please help me on how to give all permissions to second tester ?

Comment: Send them through the login flow, same as you would eventually do with normal users …?

Comment: yes ..did that too. every time i am logging with facebook  for every tester/developer/admin.

Comment: And you are asking for the permission in that flow? Has the user perhaps declined that permission before? In that case, you need to add an additional parameter (somewhere in the login documentation) to the login dialog call, to “re-ask” for already declined permissions again.

Comment: solved .....Thank you. tester 1 had 5 permissions n tester 2 had 3 permissions only. i had added tester one from my source code. tester 2 was added by other admin which had 3 permissions in that source code. so due to that this problem was arrived. ....................so please guys do not forget to sync source code.